# The same upsell products appear at any product page on magento ee 1.12.0 with FPC enabled

Tags: magento

I'm not 100% sure, but it seems like a bug in magento's built-in implementation of hole-punching for up-sell/related products.

I looked through the code and found that container for upsell/related products depends on customer session, but not on the currently viewed product.

Class responsible for upsell/related products caching called `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_CatalogProductList` and it extends `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Advanced_Quote`. This class (CatalogProductList) doesn't overwrite neither `_getCacheId` nor `_getAdditionalCacheId` methods. Thus this cache only depends on customer's session and because of that whenever any visitor visits the product page, which is not in the cache yet, magento rebuilds upsells block for that particular product and after that it is used on every product page for this customer.

As a temporary solution, I added below method into CatalogProductList class, and it fixed the issue. I know this is poor solution and I'm going to change that, but I wanted to ask if anybody had such issue and what is the solution for it.

Method which was added is

```
public function applyWithoutApp(&$content)
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like Magento EE replaces the standard `product.info.upsell` and `catalog.product.related` blocks in the layout with versions from the `Enterprise_TargetRule` extension in `design/frontend/enterprise/default/layout/targetrule.xml`:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <!-- remove name="catalog.product.related" / -->
        <block type="enterprise_targetrule/catalog_product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" as="relatedProducts" template="targetrule/catalog/product/list/related.phtml">
            <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>3</columns></action>
            <block type="enterprise_targetrule/catalog_product_item" name="catalog.product.related.item" template="targetrule/catalog/product/list/related/item.phtml" />
        </block>
        <!-- remove name="product.info.upsell" / -->
        <block type="enterprise_targetrule/catalog_product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="targetrule/catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
            <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
            <block type="enterprise_targetrule/catalog_product_item" name="catalog.product.upsell.item" template="targetrule/catalog/product/list/upsell/item.phtml" />
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

What stands out to me is that it is targeting the old versions `catalog/product_list_related` and `catalog/product_list_upsell` to use the `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_CatalogProductList` container:

```
<catalog_product_list_related>
    <block>catalog/product_list_related</block>
    <name>catalog.product.related</name>
    <placeholder>CATALOG_PRODUCT_LIST_RELATED</placeholder>
    <container>Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_CatalogProductList</container>
    <cache_lifetime>86400</cache_lifetime>
</catalog_product_list_related>
<catalog_product_list_upsell>
    <block>catalog/product_list_upsell</block>
    <name>product.info.upsell</name>
    <placeholder>CATALOG_PRODUCT_LIST_UPSELL</placeholder>
    <container>Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_CatalogProductList</container>
    <cache_lifetime>86400</cache_lifetime>
</catalog_product_list_upsell>
```

But it also is targeting the new blocks it created with a more sophisticated container `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_CatalogProductItem` that does include the product in the cache key:

```
<catalog_product_item_related>
    <block>enterprise_targetrule/catalog_product_item</block>
    <name>catalog.product.related.item</name>
    <placeholder>CATALOG_PRODUCT_ITEM_RELATED</placeholder>
    <container>Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_CatalogProductItem</container>
    <cache_lifetime>86400</cache_lifetime>
</catalog_product_item_related>
<catalog_product_item_upsell>
    <block>enterprise_targetrule/catalog_product_item</block>
    <name>catalog.product.upsell.item</name>
    <placeholder>CATALOG_PRODUCT_ITEM_UPSELL</placeholder>
    <container>Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_CatalogProductItem</container>
    <cache_lifetime>86400</cache_lifetime>
</catalog_product_item_upsell>
```

So, it makes me wonder whether you have those layout updates from `targetrule.xml` included in your current theme? If not, that would explain why the old blocks are being used rather than the new ones.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot. Target rule layout is empty in my theme. I have one question though. I was able to look on the latest implementation of CatalogProductItem, it was completely rewritten since ee 1.12. However cache key in it still depends on COOKIE_CART. Do you happen to know why is that? I don't see why this block should be unique for each customer/cart.

Comment: @anon - not sure, but maybe there are some aspects of target rules which can be affected by customer? You could experiment with extending that container to remove the session from the cache key if you know you don’t need it. Sometimes Magento’s code is not very optimized since they have to support a lot of flexibility.